# Tags with cms-X should to be renamed

Tags: discussion

We have been using the `cms-X` tags since the start, but I think we should consider changing them.

While they are semantically ok, here are some issues I've found with them:

- some users tag questions with `joomla-framework` because they fail to find the proper tag.
- Right now, till the Joomla Framework becomes popular, Joomla is the CMS, so we should not really worry about confusing the two.
- they are very bad for SEO, as they are added to the title. cms-X in the title provides no value for search engines. SEO is vital for this community as most traffic will eventually come from search engines.

How do you feel about renaming them:

cms-3.x -> joomla-3.x

and so on.

Comment: Agreed. It's probably a bit optimistic to expect those new to Joomla to be able to work out CMS vs. framework tags.

Comment: Also some alternatives would be like so: `3.x`, `v3.x` and `j3.x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed. I think it would be best using `joomla-x.x` because this is what is currently used on Stackoverflow and people are used to it. Therefore why change what already works.

I think you also make a very good point in regards to SEO.

So something like:

- CMS related = `joomla-x-x` (where the x defines the version)
- Framework related = `framework-x-x` **or** `joomla-framework`

Comment: I think this keeps things relative to the language used over at joomla.org.

Comment: I have renamed the `cms-x` tags to `joomla-x` and the `joomla-framework` to `joomla-framework-1.x`. I hope this helps from the SEO point of view and to make it easier for newbies to tag their own questions. If this is the best solution, we will see in the future.

Comment: @Valentin, thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I disagree, while the addition of cms to the title is true, I believe it will have minimal effect on SEO because

- Joomla is used in the base root of the url.
- Joomla Stack Exchange is appended to the title anyway.
- Most people use Joomla in the title and the question post.
- There are related Joomla questions in the sidebar.
- Answers usually have the word Joomla in them.

To me the overuse of the word Joomla seems unnecessary and akin to keyword stuffing (not that it is keyword stuffing).

It would be interesting to know what percentage of users are incorrectly using the tag. At the moment, I don't feel that it is occurring enough to be a problem. Most people who have used joomla.stackexchange.com for more than a few days have cottoned on to the tagging system. It's a very small learning curve.

If and when Joomla is permanently established we can use `suggested tags` to lead people towards the correct tags. Also you can add it to "How to ask correct questions" or similar resource.

If we changed the tag `joomla-framework` to `jfw` we wouldn't have this problem. I'd seriously recommend doing that anyway, joomla-framework is a long tag and like you said confusing for newcomers.

Finally, I feel that tagging with joomla-x-x is unsightly. I really hope we don't use it (but then again so is cms...).

Comment: Agree. There is no sense to put word `joomla` to the tags having dedicated SO-site.

Comment: It's to note that tags also allow for an alias. You can define synonyms. So if someone uses joomla-3.x it will automatically be matched to cms-3.x if we set that up.